# mysql avg function with ROUND function

Tags: mysql

In mysql query i have used

```
avg(column_name)
```

which return value `12.50` but if i do round to  avg function like

```
ROUND(avg(column_name))
```

then it returns value `12` but it need to be `13`. I dont know why it is returning `12` instead of `13`

If I do `ROUND(12.50)` it returns me value "13" and `avg(column_name)` which is 12.50.  When I do `ROUND(avg(column_name))` returns value "12".  I think in both cases output needs to be "13".

Answer (score 3):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-rounding.html:

> As of MySQL 5.0.3, ROUND() uses the following rules depending on the
>   type of the first argument:
>
> For exact-value numbers, ROUND() uses the “round half up” or “round
>   toward nearest” rule: A value with a fractional part of .5 or greater
>   is rounded up to the next integer if positive or down to the next
>   integer if negative. (In other words, it is rounded away from zero.) A
>   value with a fractional part less than .5 is rounded down to the next
>   integer if positive or up to the next integer if negative.
>
> For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library. On
>   many systems, this means that ROUND() uses the "round to nearest even"
>   rule: A value with any fractional part is rounded to the nearest even
>   integer.
>
> The following example shows how rounding differs for exact and
>   approximate values:

```
mysql> SELECT ROUND(2.5), ROUND(25E-1);
+------------+--------------+
| ROUND(2.5) | ROUND(25E-1) |
+------------+--------------+
| 3          |            2 |
+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ROUND(cast(avg(column_name) as decimal))
```

More Information [Rounding Behavior](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-rounding.html)

thanks for the reference [472084](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472084/472084) and [itsmeee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576190/itsmeee)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your case, but here's what is written in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

> For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library. On
>   many systems, this means that ROUND() uses the "round to nearest even"
>   rule: A value with any fractional part is rounded to the nearest even
>   integer.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
FLOOR(avg(column_name) + 0.5)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.